# Need help for find out why flutter tooltip not working in my code

Tags: flutter, datatable, tooltip

I am trying to put tooltip in data table. But the tooltip is not working.

Here, I create a data table by Name, Age and Role. I used tooltip column site for indicate information. I am using android studio. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the flutter code; please notice tooltip in data column.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main(){
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Home(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
    }
    
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Data Table"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: DataTable(
              columns: [
                DataColumn(label: Text("Name"), tooltip: "Name"),
                DataColumn(label: Text("Age"), tooltip: "Age"),
                DataColumn(label: Text("Role"), tooltip: "Role")
              ],
              rows: [
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text("Tanvir"),),
                  DataCell(Text("30"),),
                  DataCell(Text("Engineer"),),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text("Sara"),),
                  DataCell(Text("28"),),
                  DataCell(Text("Housewife"),),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text("Sadia"),),
                  DataCell(Text("35"),),
                  DataCell(Text("Manager"),),
                ]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[After run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQFgp.jpg)

Comment: Tooltip is working when tapping , see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeEfD5fI-5Q

Answer (score 7):

This code is working fine, Tooltip will only visible on Tap & Hold on the column name for the mobile app and on the hover of the web app. Try to tap and hold on column name you will see the tooltip.

I'm assuming that you are expecting an info kind of button beside the column name.

for more help on the tooltip, you can visit this link : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html

Comment: I did it but till now nothing happen. If possible you can check it by Anydesk?

Comment: In simulator it wouldn't work on hover, you have to tap and hold with the cursor in the simulator. Can you please try this?

Comment: I tried again but same result. I also restart my android studio. Only tooltip not working. I also tried another code but same not working. but those code working another and its fine.

Answer (score 1):

In web it is triggered on hover so when using simulator it wont show
In mobile the defualt is long pressed but you can customize it
triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap